# A function providing single object to recursive method

Tags: java, function, recursion

The code is posted for review on review board. My intention is not asking to review the code.

[Maze] : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33155/maze-code-review

In the above code the function `solve` does nothing but provide a stack object (reference to object of type stack) which would be used by a code executing recursively.

1. Since there are so many patterns is there a name for such a function which only assists / or does setup for recursive calls ?
2. If so any do's / dont's / alternatives ?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what are you asking for. Name of method type like factories or something?

Comment: @Antoniossss thats correct, thats what i am asking for, along with that any `time tested rules/practices` associated with such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did just fine. Every recursive algorithm needs some initial values for it's first step. It's common practice to encapsulate this initial call in another method so the caller doesn't have to bother with those values.

If your initial values would be more complicated to set up, you could encapsulate that in  additional methods too. Say your stack needs to have some content instead of being empty. You could do something like this:

```
public List<Coordinate> solve() {
    return getMazePath(0, 0, getInitialStack());
}
```

This way the `solve` method stays clear and easy as the entry point of your recursion.